# A formal justification for this "physicism"?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, physics, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I gave a presentation for a seminar class yesterday on Fourier analysis, and introduced the sawtooth function as a counterexample, for a function whose Fourier series is not termwise differentiable. This example was motivated by my claim that physicists run around willy-nilly, and differentiate term-by-term without regard for convergence.

So, in short, if $f(x)=x$ for $0\le x\le 2\pi$ and we extend by periodicity, then $f$ has Fourier series $\sum_{n\neq 0, n\in\mathbb{Z}}^\infty -\frac{1}{in} e^{inx}$, which converges pointwise (conditionally). If we differentiate termwise, we get the series $-\sum_{n\neq 0} e^{inx}$, which never converges, and yet we should have gotten $1$ off of $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

My point: just after my presentation, a friend with a greater inclination to physics actually showed a "physicist's justification" of the above series actually equaling $1$. I.e. if we pretend that the geometric sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ actually converges for $|r|=1, r\neq 1$ then we can write the above series as $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-inx}+e^{inx}=-\frac{e^{-ix}}{1-e^{-ix}}-\frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}$, which actually equals $1$ for $x\notin 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$!

My question is: is there a formal justification for this manipulation? I have in mind one involving the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, so that we can formally ignore convergence issues. The fact that this method, which is so simple, actually gives the right answer has convinced me that there must be some truth to it. Thanks for any advice or references you may be able to provide!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Operations_on_distributions

Comment: Does the series converges uniformly ?.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So this class was actually based on Friedlander & Joshi, so I'm comfortable with distributions, and I actually believe that my series converges in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ to $1-2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-2\pi n)$. Maybe to be more clear, I think I'm looking for a method that justifies using the geometric series manipulation, which I don't think distributions quite do.

And uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, so no.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid manipulation of formal Laurent series $\mathbb{C}[[e^{ix},e^{-ix}]]$. Note that formal Laurent series don't form a ring because some pairs of elements can't be multiplied, but we indeed have that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{e^{ikx}}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $1-e^{ix}$ and similarly for negative powers.

Comment: This isn't a ring? I might be wrong, but I thought this should just be $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$, which in my head is a ring.

Comment: @forgetfulfunctor Substitution doesn't work for infinite sums. That's a polynomial property. Try squaring $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{x^k}$ and you'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: But in $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/(xy-1)$ like, that polynomial is in the same equivalence class, i.e. is the same, as $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k+y^k$, which you can square nicely, right? And every Laurent series can be put like that, uniquely, can't they?

Comment: *, that series. Sorry, it says comments can only be edited for 5 minutes.

Comment: $y\mapsto x^{-1}$ does not imply that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{y^k}\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{-k}}$ because the sum is infinite.

Comment: OK, fair. So what kind of object is $\mathbb{C}[[e^{ix},e^{-ix}]]$ supposed to be then?

Comment: Almost a ring, but not a ring.

Comment: But as a positive answer, what actually is it? What category does it belong to?

Comment: @forgetfulfunctor well, it's a $\mathbb C$ vector space, and it has a product that is defined for many pairs of elements, including the ones being considered in your question. There are some things that are not necessarily usefully considered as elements of a particular category. This object doesn't have very nice morphisms.

Comment: Do you know of anywhere I could read about such kind of construct in more detail, by any chance? I haven't ever seen rings except which are semigroups under multiplication, so I can't see how this fits into any bigger mathematical theory.

Comment: @forgetfulfunctor I learned it in a graduate course taught by James Lepowsky about vertex operator algebras. It was important for the course but certainly not the whole focus. He wrote a textbook on vertex operator algebras, but I haven't read it honestly so I can't recommend it in good conscience. So I have told you all I know.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, that's helpful. I doubt I'll be able to understand his book, but I'll give it a shot and see if it contains an answer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @forgetfulfunctor You don't even really need to go to something that advanced, I shouldn't think. For example, the two simplifications really do happen in each separate power series ring. In ${\mathbb{C}}[[e^{ix}]]$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{e^{ikx}}=\frac{e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}$.

Comment: You're right. I think I need to ask my friend in what context he used this "trick" so that I can see what physical quantity the expression $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{ikx}$ represents, so I know how to think of your $\mathbb{C}[[e^{ix}]]$ as a collection of physical objects, i.e. interpret it physically.